# How to plot/display ".dat" files using gnuplot in Python

Tags: python, gnuplot

I'm currently trying to plot my data using gnuplot. I have several .dat files in a folder, and I wish to plot all my data using some simple command/script (see below). How can I make it work?

I'm using this piece currently:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color
set output "DMF-10-8-.eps"
set xrange[1:10]
set yrange[0:1]
plot "DMF-10-8.dat" using 1:2 with lines title "XXX", "DMF-10-8-wmnuy9.dat" using 1:2 with     lines title "YYY"
```

Comment: What is the problem with this method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot a lot of files, name them in a particular sequence. Then use the [`gnuplot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot) module in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) to plot them consecutively with a loop.